# keras, what is the meaning of model(data)

Tags: python, model, keras, sequential

```
class MNISTModel:
    def __init__(self, restore, session=None):
        self.num_channels = 1
        self.image_size = 28
        self.num_labels = 10

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
                         input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(200))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dense(200))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dense(10))
        model.load_weights(restore)

        self.model = model
        print('selfMNIST')

    def predict(self, data):
        tmp=self.model(data)  #Question is here
        return tmp
```

What is this sentence "tmp=self.model(data)" for?
"model" here is the variable of Class sequential, I never see such usage.
This code is taken from ## Copyright (C) 2016, Nicholas Carlini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, it depends on what `data` is but certainly the code snippet is *misleading*. To clarify:

- If you call model directly you need to pass *tensors*, it acts like another layer. `model(anotherlayer)` works for example. But if you pass actual data such as a NumPy error it will give this error:

  > ValueError: Layer sequential_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: [array(...)]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
- If you want to predict, as in pass some numeric data and run the network / propagate values / compute output then you need to `model.predict(data)` which is why it is misleading as it is a predict function.

My guess is that the author needed to chain models together and edited the `predict` function of the class instead of creating a different class function.

Comment: Thanks! It should act as another layer, 'cause it passes tensors. I don't understand "another layer". The comment when the author calls the defined function "predict" is "# prediction BEFORE-SOFTMAX of the model" (in the l2_attack.py).  BTW, Class MNISTModel is defined in the "setup_mnist.py". The full code is at github "https://github.com/carlini/nn_robust_attacks".

Comment: Can you give me some document about the use of model(data)?

Comment: `anotherlayer` is like `Dense`, an actual layer, have a look at [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) documentation that will help.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps!